# Access protected member through friend

Tags: c++

Say class B inherits class A, and B `friend`s C. Class A has a protected member `foo`.

May class C access `foo`? Are there any differences between C++ standard revisions?

Example:

```
class A {
protected:
    void foo() {}
};

class B : public A {
    friend class C;
};

class C {
    void func() {
        B b;
        b.foo();
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you provide a code sample for what you actually asking of? How exactly is `class C` related to `class A` and `class B`? That `A` is a `friend` class of `C` doesn't change anything for `class C` actually by means of access rights at `class B` or `class A`.

Comment: Should've just tried this yourself, but I edited your question to contain the code you describe, and answered it.

Comment: @David I would have preferred the OP had clarified that themselves, instead of you banging the unclear question in shape to match with your answer (I'm tempted to rollback your edit).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry I meant to provide a code sample myself in later edit. Didn't have the time I suppose :-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The code he was describing was fairly clear, if I wasn't sure what he was asking I wouldn't have bothered clarifying it.

Comment: @David The reason I did not try it myself was because I was not sure of how to ensure it was not compiler or standard version specific. I simply do not have all versions at my disposal. And c++ is occationally tricky in my experience.

Comment: Sometimes there are compiler bugs, sometimes there are non-standard implementations (usually only for cutting edge new features), but you can't be expected to question whether every regular language feature behaves correctly across compilers. Gotta make the assumption they do, about most things.

Comment: @David You are right. I´ll remove "difference between compilers" from the question leaving only "difference between c++ standard revisions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `C` has access to `B::foo`. Friends have access to anything you have access to. Since `B` can access `foo`, so can `C` access `B::foo`. `friend`s don't, however, have access to friends of friends.

No, there is no difference between compilers on this matter that I'm aware of.

Comment: Good answer (and edit). Didn´t cross my mind of asking about "friends´ friends". I will wait for a while before marking this THE answer in case some c++ guru comes with references and quotes from standard(s) the next few days. What "you are aware of" is a guess as good as mine.